# How do I create a full html anchor link based on column values

Tags: excel

I have 4 total columns in my excel document.

The first column has a list of URI paths, (ex: `http://path-to-site`)

The second column as a date that looks like this `3/31/2016  3:59:00 PM`

The third column as the Title for that page (ex: `Some Title`)

How can I append both of these values into column 4 to look like this

```
<a href="http://path-to-site/" title="3/31/2016 3:59:00 PM">Some Title</a>
```

Yes I want the cell data to look just like this HTML anchor link code.  But I can't figure it out because of the anchor link attributes that have double quotes...not sure how to formulate that into an excel column.

I have tried playing with the following technique within a cell:

```
="<a href="""&C2&""...
```

But no luck.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape quotes, use double quotes: `""`:

```
="<a href="""&A1&""" title="""&B1&""">"&TEXT(C1,"M/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM")&"</a>"
```

Comment: almost perfect but when I did this process into a new cell, the date changed.  It's no longer looking like 3/31/2016 3:59:00 PM, instead it is now 42460.66597222222.  Is there any easy way to keep the date format the same for B1?

Comment: Looks like you need a to format the date. See my updated answer.

Comment: you are an excel genius!  Thank you.